# Encode Scrapy data to display in Django and Android

Tags: python, django, json, encoding, scrapy

I'm having a nightmare with data scrapped with Scrapy. Currently I encode it using UTF-8 i.e `detail_content.select('p/text()[1]').extract()[0].encode('utf-8')` saved into a JSON file, and then the captured text is displayed again using Django and a mobile app.

In the JSON file the escaped HTML gets escaped using unicode `'blah blah \u00a34,000 blah'`

Now my problem is when I try and display the text in a django template or the mobile app the actual literal characters display: `\u00a3` instead of `£`

Should I not be storing escaped unicode in JSON? Would it be better to store ASCII in the JSON file using the JSON escaping? If so how do you go about doing this with scrapy?

**Scrappy code:**

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
import datetime
import unicodedata
import re

class Spider(BaseSpider):
    #spider stuff

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        rows = hxs.select('//ul[@class = "category3"]/li')
        for row in rows:
            item = Item()
            if len(row.select('div[2]/a/text()').extract()) > 0:
                item['header'] = str(row.select('div[2]/a/text()')
                                    .extract()[0].encode('utf-8'))
            else:
                item['header'] = ''
            if len(row.select('div[2]/a/text()').extract()) > 0:
                item['_id'] = str(row.select('div[2]/a/text()')
                                    .extract()[0].encode('utf-8'))
            else:
                item['_id'] = ''
            item['_id'] = self.slugify(item['_id'])[0:20]
            item_url = row.select('div[2]/a/@href').extract()
            today = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
            item['dateAdded'] = str(today)
            yield Request(item_url[0], meta={'item' : item},
                             callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        detail_content = hxs.select('//*[@id="content-area"]')
        item = response.request.meta['item']   
        item['description'] = str(detail_content.select('p/text()[1]')
                                                        .extract()[0])
        item['itemUrl'] = str(detail_content.select('//a[@title="Blah"]/@href')
                                                                 .extract()[0])
        item['image_urls'] = detail_content.select('//img[@width="418"]/../@href')
                                                                        .extract()
        print item
        return item
```

Comment: Have you tried without `encode('utf-8')`? Other question, what's the output of: `detail_content.select('p/text()[1]').extract()[0]`. I mean, is it `u'blah blah'` or just `'blah blah'`

Comment: Also, how are you outputting the json in the templates?

Comment: Yeah tried without encode('utf-8'), I receive errors like: `exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 127: ordinal not in range(128)`

i'm outputting the text in the django templates in the regular way i.e. `{{ item.description }}` autoescaping on or off makes no difference

Comment: Can you post more background of your code. Normally, if you're encoding in `utf-8` the string \u00a3 shouldn't appear in the `.json` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this I find very odd:

```
item['header'] = str(row.select('div[2]/a/text()')
                     .extract()[0].encode('utf-8'))
```

Is not correct to do `str(<some_value>.encode('utf-8'))`. That basically means you're converting a utf-8 bunch of bytes to ascii. This may yield errors when the utf-8 bytes exceed 128.

Now, I strongly believe your getting the characters from Scrappy already in unicode.

> I receive errors like: `exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 127: ordinal not in range(128)`

So, my suggestion is to change the code to this:

```
item['header'] = row.select('div[2]/a/text()')
                 .extract()[0].encode('utf-8')
```

Just remove the `str()` calling. This will get the unicode received from Scrappy and turn it into `utf-8`. Once it is in `utf-8`. Be careful with string operations. Normally this conversion from unicode to a specific encoding should be done just before the writing to disk.

**Note** that you have this kind of code in two places. Modify them both.

**UPDATE:** Take a look at this, might be helpful: [scrapy text encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181214/scrapy-text-encoding)

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're right about the str() it's not required. Not sure why I was using it so thank you! However I've still got the same problem. There is no unicode escape characters in the original HTML. Scrapy looks like it's taking the HTML and converts it into UTF-8 before anything else happens

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand first. So there's no unicode scaped char in the original HTML. What Scrapy may be doing is converting it to Unicode but not `utf-8`

Comment: Do you still get \u00a3 in your .json file?

Comment: Just checked, yes it's unicode not utf-8 sorry, I only assumed it was utf-8 as I've got that my code. Yes still get \u00a3. All the non standard characters get escaped \uXXXX

Comment: Can you post how do you write the `.json` file?

Comment: `scrapy crawl myspider -o items.json -t json`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32084/discussion-between-paulo-bu-and-kingfu)

Comment: the link you posted has the solution, creating custom pipeline