# Why Do I get an empty output in scrapy for my items?

Tags: python, scrapy, python-unicode

I'm a newbie in python and scrapy. I'm going to scrape a page of some links to get my desired data but when i generate my output, my desired items are empty.

My items.py code is as follows:

```
class CinemaItem(Item):
    url = Field()
    name = Field()
    pass
```

My cinema_spider.py is as follows:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from cinema.items import CinemaItem

class CinemaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "cinema"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.example.com/?user=artists"
    ]
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=['/\?user=profile&detailid=\d+']),'parse_cinema')]

    def parse_cinema(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        cinema = CinemaItem()
        cinema['url'] = response.url
        cinema['name'] = hxs.select("//html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/text()").extract()
        return cinema
```

when i run the following command:

```
scrapy crawl cinema -o scraped_data.json -t json
```

The output file has such a content:

```
[{"url": "http://www.example.com/?detailid=218&user=profile", "name": []},
{"url": "http://www.example.com/?detailid=322&user=profile", "name": []},
{"url": "http://www.example.com/?detailid=219&user=profile", "name": []},
{"url": "http://www.example.com/?detailid=221&user=profile", "name": []}]
```

As you see, the name items are empty, although in fact, they have values and i can get them when i fetch them in scrapy shell. But, since their values are in Persian language and probably in unicode format, the output in shell is as:

```
[u'\u0631\u06cc\u062d\u0627\u0646\u0647 \u0628\u0627\u0642\u0631\u06cc \u0628\u0627\u06cc\u06af\u06cc']
```

I changes the spider code as following to change the items encoding:

```
cinema['name'] = hxs.select("//html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/text()").extract()[0].encode('utf-8')
```

But got such an error:

```
cinema['name'] = hxs.select("//html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/text()").extract()[0].encode('utf-8')
exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range
```

Then, i undo that change to my spider code, and according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181214/scrapy-text-encoding), wrote my own pipelines.py to change the default value of ensure_ascii and turn it into "False":

```
import json
import codecs

class CinemaPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.file = codecs.open('scraped_data_utf8.json', 'wb', encoding='utf-8')

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(dict(item), ensure_ascii=False) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.file.close()
```

But, the resulted output file was the same with empty name items.

I read almost all posts in stackoverflow about this issue but can't resolve that. What's the problem?

Edited:

Some snippet of HTML:

```
<div class="content font-fa" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="content-box">
        <div class="content-text" dir="rtl" style="width:240px;min-height:200px;text-align:center"><img src='../images/others/no-photo.jpg' ></div>
        <div class="content-text" dir="rtl" style="width:450px;float:right;min-height:200px;" >
            <div class="content-row" style="text-align:right;margin-right:0px;">
                <span class="FontsFa">
                    <span align="right">
                        <strong class="font-11 "> نام/نام خانوادگی : </strong>
                    </span>
                    <span class="large-title">
                        <span class="bold font-13" style="color:#900;">ریحانه باقری بایگی
                        </span>
                    </span>
               </span>
            </div>
```

I want to get the text between `<span class="bold font-13" style="color:#900;">ریحانه باقری بایگی
                            </span>`

Comment: It worked. I don't know what happened but today, without any change in code, it is working right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is very probably that your XPath doesn't match your wanted data.

`hxs.select(...).extract()` will get you an empty array, when you try to change encoding you're calling `hxs.select(...).extract()[0]` which throws an `IndexError`.

How did you find that XPath? Did you test it inside of your spider? Beware that **HTML as shown in browser and in scrapy might be different**, usually because scrapy doesn't execute javascript. As a general rule you should always check `response.body` to be what you expect.

Also, your XPath is very easily breakable because it uses absolute positions. This means that any change anywhere in your path will break the whole thing. Usually it is best to try and rely on ids or unique characteristics (`//td[id="foobar"]`).

Could you provide a relevant snippet of the HTML you're trying to parse?

Comment: Thanks. As i said, this xpath works well in `scrapy shell` and outputs exactly the data i want, but in ascii format, although when i `print` it, shows it with the right encoding,too.
And, about my xpath breakability i should say that i know that but since the given html code is not standard and IDs are not unique i have wrtie the xpath in that form. anyway, i added some snippet of HTML to my question.

Comment: I found this xpath by Firebog addon. How can i test it inside of my spider?

Comment: Well the IndexError is thrown because the `hxs.select(...).extract()` is an empty array... Since there is no data there, modifying the pipeline which comes afterwards won't change anything. How did you retrieve that info with the shell? Same code? BTW to easily debug your code you should use the python debugger, [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) (or you can even install [ipdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb) for cool features like completion)