# Give wrong output when make csv file

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

class PushpaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://adv-tver.ru/lawyer/Pokrovskij184']
    
  
    def parse(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath("//table[@class='table']")[1:]
        for row in rows:
            a=row.xpath("//tr[1]//td[2]//text()").get()
            b=row.xpath("//tr[2]//td[2]//text()").get()
            c=row.xpath("//tr[3]//td[2]//text()").get()
            d=row.xpath("//tr[4]//td[2]//text()").get()
            e=row.xpath("//tr[5]//td[2]//text()").get()
            f=row.xpath("//tr[6]//td[2]//text()").get()
            g=row.xpath("//tr[7]//td[2]//text()").get()
            yield{
                'Ф.И.О.:':a,
                }
```

WHen I  run the code in terminal they will give me `correct output`:

```
'Ф.И.О.:': 'Покровский\xa0Василий\xa0Васильевич'
```

When I MAKE `CSV FILE` THEY GIVE Me wrong output as show below:

```
Ð¤.Ð˜.Ðž.:ÐŸÐ¾ÐºÑ€Ð¾Ð²ÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹Â Ð’Ð°ÑÐ¸Ð»Ð¸Ð¹Â Ð’Ð°ÑÐ¸Ð»ÑŒÐµÐ²Ð¸Ñ‡
```

Comment: Show your code that creates the CSV file.

Comment: `scrapy crawl test -O link.csv`  these is the way I create csv file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181214/scrapy-text-encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are using absolute xpath expressions in your for loop when they should be relative expressions.
- Also you need to set your `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING` setting to 'utf-8'.

For example:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

class PushpaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://adv-tver.ru/lawyer/Pokrovskij184']
    custom_settings = {"FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING": 'utf-8'}
    
  
    def parse(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath("//table[@class='table']")[1:]
        for row in rows:
            a=row.xpath("./tr[1]//td[2]//text()").get()
            b=row.xpath("./tr[2]//td[2]//text()").get()
            c=row.xpath("./tr[3]//td[2]//text()").get()
            d=row.xpath("./tr[4]//td[2]//text()").get()
            e=row.xpath("./tr[5]//td[2]//text()").get()
            f=row.xpath("./tr[6]//td[2]//text()").get()
            g=row.xpath("./tr[7]//td[2]//text()").get()
            yield ...
```